# Is this a virus? Hexagonal shaped icon preventing Windows 10 shutdown

Tags: windows-10, shutdown, virus, malware, spyware

This app is preventing a shutdown in Windows 10, and I cannot find it in the process list.

Any ideas what it is?  Do you know what this icon is for?

[image: File icon preventing shutdown]

Comment: At a guess, it's seems unlikely it would have such a distinctive icon if it was a virus.

Comment: usually app name is listed there as well

Comment: You never know with these virus writing people these days, they go to all sorts of lengths to dup people, so trying to figure it out thanks so far :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's the icon for a program called [Snagit](http://www.unitedaddins.com/product/snagit/) by United Add-ins.

Comment: I use snag it, from techsmith, must be it. Or maybe a virus has taken over it, as it hasn't worked for a couple of weeks. Thanks for the direction.

Comment: @CraigLambie, if it hangs when you shut down and hasn't worked for a few weeks, it may have gotten corrupted.  You could try reinstalling the application.  This isn't unusual for any software; there's no reason to assume there's a virus (this isn't typical malware behavior).